# Unregistered Class Toggling

Tags: javascript, css, classname

So I've been working in assembly for awhile and just came back to websites after quite some time and one of the questions that are still bothering me today is, why can't I change a class from one animation (open/slide into view animation) to the other (close/slide out of view animation)? I have been being required to set up four different class names to achieve this such as:

```
.open {
    height: 50px;
    animation: keyframe 1s forwards 1 0s;
}
.opened {
    height: 50px;
}
.close {
    height: 0;
    animation: keyframe 1s reverse forwards 1 0s;
}
closed {
    height: 0;
}
```

And then in my javascript I am forced to add the keyframe set a timeout and then change to the one without a keyframe otherwise if for say close is already happened and is left on without changing to a class without an animation and in javascript I make it go from close straight to open it will NOT do the open animation? So I've been having to do something like this in javascript:

```
        if (window.pageYOffset == 0 && !elm.classList.contains("closed")) {
            elm.className = "close";
            setTimeout(() => {
                elm.className = "closed";
            }, 1000);
        } else if (window.pageYOffset > 0 && !elm.classList.contains("opened")) {
            elm.className = "open";
            setTimeout(() => {
                elm.className = "opened";
            }, 1000);
        }
```

What I'm wanting to do is this though:

```
        if (window.pageYOffset == 0 && !elm.classList.contains("close")) {
            elm.className = "close";
        } else if (window.pageYOffset > 0 && !elm.classList.contains("open")) {
            elm.className = "open";
        }
```

But if you do that the browser, I am using is Google Chrome, will NOT switch and do the animation, and this brings me to the next part of my question what is the required timeout time in this case? It seems I have to at least have a timeout greater than 50ms for it to register the class switch and do the animations? How do I calculate the required time frame? I assume I am supposed to create an infinite loop on the after the remove class name portion and then once it is removed activate the second part of adding the other classname? I have to do this for example:

```
elm.className = "";
setTimeout(() => {
    elm.className = "new_class"
}, 50);
```

This example is to show how I am being forced to at least remove the current "close" animation wait for timeout and then add the "open" animation but what I do not know is what is the required time frame for this timeout to be efficient? I have seen using anything less than 50ms will be unregistered and will not do the new animation.

Comment: The css rule for `closed` is malformed.  It does not have a closing `}`.  Also the way you have the css rules, once you remove the `open` or `close` class from an element, it will no longer have an animation rule associated with it

Comment: This is true. Now why must I remove the classname with an animation prior to switching to a different classname with a different animation? Also thank you I will fix the posts css.

Comment: And by that I am meaning I can't just do 

if (elm.classList.contains("close")) {
elm.className = "open";
} else {
elm.className = "close";
}

Comment: I'm not a CSS guru by any means, however from my past experiences with css rules like this, typically I would have one class that the element has that defines which property on the element will be animated.  And then I would have other classes that manipulate the state of that property.  For instance, the base class (that does not get removed) would say height is animated (for example).  I would then have a class that sets the height to 50px, and another to 0.  Toggling the secondary classes lets CSS know what the value should become, and the root class that never changes, says to animate it.

Comment: Did you try using classList.add and remove APIs instead of className ?

Comment: Yes I have what I am trying to do is have one base class and then a single open and close class animation but what I'm having to do is have one base class then an open and close class to animate and then a opened and closed class that removes the animations for the switch to the animations to work. If I switch from one animation to the other animation the animation I switch to will never be activated. It seems as if it gets changed to quickly for css to register the new animation which leaves me forced to use a timeout with 50ms+ in order for it to register? I'm looking for a way around this